# Prove or disprove: For any $v\in\mathbb{R}^n, \|v\|_1\|v\|_\infty \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{n}}{2}\|v\|_2^2$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

I know that $\|v\|_1\|v\|_\infty \leq (1+\sqrt{n})\|v\|_2^2$, but cannot find a way to refine this bound. Does anyone know where would be a good place to start? Trying out several cases seems to imply that the inequality is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose that the vector $v$ consists of non-negative values $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\geq 0$ such that $\|v\|_\infty=v_1$. Therefore it is enough to find a $c$ such that for all these vectors we have:
$$
v_1(v_1+\dots+v_n)\leq c(v_1^2+\dots+v_n^2).
$$
See that:
$$
c(v_1^2+\dots+v_n^2)-v_1(v_1+\dots+v_n)=(c-1)v_1^2+cv_2^2+\dots+cv_n^2-v_1v_2-\dots-v_1v_n.
$$
However:
$$
\frac{c-1}{n-1}v_1^2+cv_i^2=(\sqrt{\frac{c-1}{n-1}}v_1-\sqrt cv_i)^2+2\sqrt{\frac{c(c-1)}{n-1}}v_1v_i.
$$
Then it can be seen that for $c\geq \frac{1+\sqrt n}2$, we have:
$$
2\sqrt{\frac{c(c-1)}{n-1}}v_1v_i-v_1v_i\geq 0.
$$
This implies the inequality for all $c\geq \frac{1+\sqrt n}2$.

Comment: Very nice.  I want to add that the AM-GM Inequality can be used to prove this part:  $$\frac{c-1}{n-1}\,v_1^2+c\,v_i^2\geq 2\sqrt{\frac{c(c-1)}{n-1}}\,v_1v_i\,.$$